# What is the Mercurial equivalent for showing commits in one branch but not in another?

Tags: mercurial

In git, I can do the following:

```
git log foo ^bar
```

to show changesets in the branch `foo` but not in the branch `bar`. Is there a way to do that in Mercurial?

**Edit:** To explain a little more the use case. Say I have a branch in Mercurial (call it `foo`) that is branched off of `default`. What I want to know is what commits are in the `foo` branch, and therefore haven't been merged to `default`. Maybe I'm thinking of this the wrong way, but in git, I could start working on `foo`, merge to `master` and then work some more on `foo` and use the command above to see which commits had yet to be merged in.

So a specific use case is knowing whether a branch has been completed merged into default. From using Mercurial, if I start a branch `foo` off of `default` to work on one feature, then leave it there so be merged and branch off of `foo` to create `bar`, which contains another feature built on top of things in `foo`, `foo` ends up being inactive because `bar` contains all the changesets in foo, but I may want to merge just the changesets in `foo` because I know those are good while `bar` is still in development. Hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: So you basically want to see all ancestors of `foo` that are not part of the ancestors of `default`. That’s indeed what the second half of my answer does.

Comment: If you just want to view the commits in one branch, just use `hg log -b <branch>`. If `<branch>` is your current branch, you can use `hg log -b .`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) (`hg help revsets`)

```
hg log -r "branch(foo) and not branch(bar)"
```

But this is kind of useless as a changeset can only be in one named branch at a time.

Maybe you mean all ancestors of a bookmark that are not ancestor of another bookmark?

```
hg log -r "::a and not ::b"
```

Either way, the revsets help page should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, revsets is what I was looking for. I think I meant to say "changesets" instead of "commits," so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah changeset is Mercurial lingo, commit is Git lingo ;p. You can use them pretty much interchangeably.

Answer (score 11):

What exactly do you mean by commits in branch foo but not in bar? Commits are fundamentally only in one branch in mercurial.

```
hg log -b foo  #lists all commits that are in branch foo
```

Comment: See my edit above. When you say "commits are fundamentally only in one branch in mercurial," does that mean the model is different from Git? My understanding was there are just changesets and you can apply them to any branch, so two branches could both have a changeset applied.

Comment: I edited my question to be "changesets" instead of "commits," thanks for pointing out that mistake.

Comment: @Bialecki, Mercurial has two types of branches, named branches and anonymous branches. Anonymous branches are nothing more than diverging commits, and they can be tracked with bookmarks (which are similar to what git’s branches). Named branches actually get a label committed along with them, so a commit is always on one branch, either 'default' or another.

Comment: @Bialecki: As for what to use when: named branches are useful for long-lived branches such as release branches, because when looking at a commit while browsing the history you can see what branch it was originally developed on. This gives you better context. These type of branches don’t have a git equivalent, and working with git I miss this when trying to decipher the commit history. Anonymous branches are more useful for daily development. They just ‘start to exist’ and you can label them afterwards, whereas for feature branches you have to decide ahead of time to make a branch.

Answer (score 4):

to show changesets in the branch foo but not in the branch bar

```
hg log -r "::foo and not ::bar and ! destination(branch(bar)) and ! origin(branch(bar))"
```

Comment: This filters out changesets that have been grafted from foo to bar. So this is particularly useful for answering the question "If I merge foo to bar, which changesets will that introduce to bar that haven't been there before?"